# Keep rows with more valid values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with this structure:

```
    Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4     Col5     Col6
    Apple    1.0      
    Apple    1.0      Fruit    Green    0.99      OK
    Apple                      Green    0.99
    Apple                               0.99
    Banana   2.0      Fruit    Yellow   1.29      
    Banana   2.0     
    Banana   2.0      Fruit    
    Coconut  2.2      
    Coconut           Fruit          
    Coconut  2.2      Fruit    Brown              OK
```

I need keep the rows with more values informated.

The dataframe that i need with this example:

```
    Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4     Col5     Col6
    Apple    1.0      Fruit    Green    0.99      OK
    Banana   2.0      Fruit    Yellow   1.29
    Coconut  2.2      Fruit    Brown              OK
```

I need to apply this logic to a lot of dataframes (pyspark).

Edit: The No-Informeted values are not nulls, just cols without characters '(no-whitespace)'.

Comment: How do you defined "with more values informated"? For each row, you can easily compute the number of filled columns, but then which rows do you keep? Do you want to use a treshold (eg keep all rows with more than 4 columns filled) or keep a defined percentage (eg the top 10%) ?

Comment: I need to keep the row with more cols filled. Not treshold

Comment: Ok I understand. You want to keep the rows whose number of filled columns is equal to the maximum of  the numbers of column filled for a row.

Answer (score 0):

For each value, convert it to boolean indicating wether the cell is filled.
Sum on each row. Keep the rows with the maximum sum.

Here is the code, where `df` is your input dataframe.

```
nb_col_filled = df.notna().sum(axis=1)
result_df = df[nb_col_filled==nb_col_filled.max()]
```

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

Just use `max` to get the "max" value of each column

###### sample data

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ( 'Apple' ,  '1.0',      '',      '',     '',   ''),
    ( 'Apple' ,  '1.0', 'Fruit', 'Green', '0.99', 'OK'),
    ( 'Apple' ,     '',      '', 'Green', '0.99',   ''),
    ( 'Apple' , '0.99',      '',      '',     '',   ''),
    ( 'Banana',  '2.0', 'Fruit', 'Yello', '1.29',   ''),
    ( 'Banana',  '2.0',      '',      '',     '',   ''),
    ( 'Banana',  '2.0', 'Fruit',      '',     '',   ''),
    ('Coconut',  '2.2',      '',      '',     '',   ''),
    ('Coconut',     '', 'Fruit',      '',     '',   ''),
    ('Coconut',  '2.2', 'Fruit', 'Brown',     '', 'OK'),
], ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5', 'Col6'])
```

###### Applying `max`

```py
(df
    .groupBy('Col1')
    .agg(
        F.max('Col2').alias('Col2'),
        F.max('Col3').alias('Col3'),
        F.max('Col4').alias('Col4'),
        F.max('Col5').alias('Col5'),
        F.max('Col6').alias('Col6'),
    )
    .show()
)

+-------+----+-----+-----+----+----+
|   Col1|Col2| Col3| Col4|Col5|Col6|
+-------+----+-----+-----+----+----+
|  Apple| 1.0|Fruit|Green|0.99|  OK|
| Banana| 2.0|Fruit|Yello|1.29|    |
|Coconut| 2.2|Fruit|Brown|    |  OK|
+-------+----+-----+-----+----+----+
```